# openjpa metamodel tool doesn't generate metamodel

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, annotation-processing, metamodel

I'm trying to generate a metamodel in an existing maven project.  The project already has a few data sources with metamodels being generated in generated-sources.

I need to add a table from a new DB to this app.  I generated the java class &  entries to an XML config.  The build  log message below seems to indicate that openjpa is finding my config entry, but no metamodel classes get generated.  Furthermore, no errors or warnings related to my new data  source are in the log.

I'm at a total loss on how to figure out what I missed.

This is the following message:

```
9999  for.metamodel.only  INFO   [main] openjpa.Tool - Enhancer running on type "class com.test.table".
```

Can any of you point me in the right direction for finding out what I'm clearly  missing?

Answer (score 2):

I was missing the @Entity attribute at the top of my persistence class.  Seems like this should have generated a warning.  I mean, I went to the trouble of providing a config entry pointing to the class.